# Facebook Api Upgrade Tool Evaluations

Tags: facebook

When I look for "items to fix to upgrade" area for my Facebook application I see returns like:

[Api Upgrade Tool Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZiE1.png)

However, I am using the latest sdk as follows:

Html:

```
 <script src="/Content/scripts/facebook/sdk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Javascipt:

```
   window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
    appId: '<%=ConstantValues.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID%>',
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.8'
   });
   FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
   };

   (function (d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

and making calls with get as follows:

```
  var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
  dynamic fbUser = fb.Get("me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,birthday,location,gender");
```

What am I missing and why am I getting that returns in my api calls?

(I use ASP.NET, C# and Facebook Nuget package v7.0.6 and despite all changes I made my application version is still 2.2)

Comment: Are you requesting the user’s activities and interests anywhere …?

Comment: No, to be sure I also searched the words "interests" and "activities" in my entire solution and there were no significant matching lines. fb.GetLoginUrl(...) with scope _"public_profile,email,user_birthday,user_location"_ and fb.Get("me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,birthday,locati‌​‌​on,gender") are the only GET operations I use. @CBroe

Comment: Well if everything works when you use v2.8, then I would not worry about it. (Are you sure you specified the API version in your server-side code as well?)

Comment: _“despite all changes I made my application version is still 2.2”_ – if you are referring to the API version shown in app dashboard - that is only the _minimum_ API version your app can use.

Comment: Yes, I specified the API version in my server-side code. I would not worry about the version shown in app dashboard if I hadn't get the evaluation return as (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KYrO.png) about my call volume. Assuming evaluations are valid, I tried to find out the source of calls which I couldn't really figure out how.

Comment: Can the evaluations be invalid in my case? What should I change? sdk.js or nuget package? Note: Other than the GET operations I use

`POST oauth/access_token
POST {user-id}/feed
POST {user-id}/notifications
DELETE {user-id}/permissions and DELETE me/permissions`, nothing more. @CBroe

Comment: I don’t know what date range this data is collected from; it might be that what the tool shows doesn’t actually apply any more, if you have made changes already. Again: _Testing_ your app to see if everything it does still works after you set it to use v2.8 everywhere, is your best bet.

Comment: Tests on the website are ok, but having trouble in connecting to facebook from my mobile application. I thought the problem was because of versioning since the problem occured after facebook forced me to upgrade from v2.1. It may completely be another issue. Thank you for your comments @CBroe